# Is every sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ such that $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=0$ a member of $\ell^p$ for some $p>0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

For every sequence of real numbers $(x_n)_{n\in N}$ converging to zero, does there exist a positive number p such that the sum $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p$ converges.

I'm not 100% sure if this is correct, but I think that the answer is yes, there exists a positive number such that the sum converges because the sequence is the absolute value and converges to 0, so it wouldn't matter how $p$ would change as long as it is positive the sum will converge.

Is that correct? Also I am struggling to show this thought with equations and calculations, so  if anybody has any ideas for that I would be very grateful.

Comment: Although $x_n=\frac1n$ converges to $0,\;$ $\sum \lvert x_n\rvert^p$ does not converge when $p=1$, which is positive $p$

Comment: It can also be false for $p=2$ , if you take $x_n=1/\sqrt{n}$ , for example.

Comment: For a series to converge , it is necessary but not sufficient that the summands build a sequence tending to $0$.

Comment: But I realize that your question is different : A sequence tending to $0$ is given and we search a positive real number $p$ such that the given sum converges. Not sure whether this is true. The above examples are not counterexamples for this.

Comment: Yes this is the same way I understood this question, so that's why I think it wouldn't matter what positive no. p it would be the sum will converge regardless

Comment: It is not true that $p$ does not matter , as shown ! The question is whether we can choose always $p$ large enough so that it does the job. Probably not , but I have no idea how a counterexample looks like.

Comment: Try $x_n = 1/\log(n+1)$

Comment: @RobertIsrael I tried it and I think it answers the question getting p=0,infinity, right?

Comment: You asked for $p$ to be a positive number, not $p=0$ or $p=\infty$

Comment: @whpowell96 yes what I meant was $p=(0,\infty)$ so anything in between as long as it's positive

Comment: @ugjumb $\sum_{n=1}^\infty 1/\log(n+1)^p$ diverges for all $p \in (0,\infty)$.  Use limit comparison test with $\sum_n 1/n$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the function $f:[1,\infty)\to[1,\infty)$ given by $f(x)=x^x$. It is bijective, so it has an inverse function $g$. I claim that $x_n=\frac{1}{g(n)}$ is a counterexample.

Since $g(n)$ is monotonically increasing to infinity, we get that $x_n$ converges monotonically to $0$. Since $g$ is strictly positive, we don't need to bother with absolute values. Finally, let's pick some real number $p\geq 1$.

Note that $(p,p^p)$ is (along with $(1,1)$) an intersection point between $f$ and $x^p$, and after this $f$ is forever larger. This means that $(p^p, p)$ is an intersection point of $g$ and $\sqrt[p]x$, and after this $g$ is forever smaller. That means that for $n\geq p^p$, we have $x_n\geq \frac1{n^{1/p}}$. This means that $$\sum_{i=\lceil p^p\rceil}^\infty x_n^p$$ is term-for-term larger than $$\sum_{i=\lceil p^p\rceil}^\infty \frac1n$$ and therefore diverges to infinity.

It is quite obvious that no $p\in(0,1)$ would work either, as all $x_n$ are less than or equal to $1$, and thus $x_n\mapsto x_n^p$ is deceasing in $p$, meaning choosing a smaller $p$ makes all terms larger.